# How can we calculate average difference of datetime fields from related table in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset

I have two models **Gigs** and **Orders**.
and want to calculate the average of diffrence between **order_start_time** and **order_completed_time**  of every gig. check my code its giving following error

Cannot resolve keyword 'orders' into field. Choices are: category, category_id, details, gig, id, images, price, reviews, seller, seller_id, title

please help!

**Models.py** (in seller app)

```
class Gigs(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images = models.ImageField(blank=True, null = True, upload_to= upload_path)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    details = models.TextField()
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User,default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 
    @property
    def average_completionTime(self):
        if self._average_completionTime is not None:
            return self._average_completionTime
        return self.gig.aggregate(Avg('order_completed_time'-'order_start_time'))
```

I think here the problem is in average completion time how can I use 'order_completed_time'-'order_start_time' in one variable that I should refer in views.py

**Models.py**(in buyer app)

focus on item field

```
from seller.models import Gigs
class Orders(models.Model):
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(User,default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='buyer_id')
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User,default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='seller_id')
    item = models.ForeignKey(Gigs,default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='gig')
    payment_method= models.CharField(max_length=10)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=13,default=None)
    quantity = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=13,default='new order')
    order_start_time = models.DateTimeField(default=None)
    order_completed_time = models.DateTimeField(default=None)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**Views.py**

```
class RetrieveGigsAPI(GenericAPIView, RetrieveModelMixin):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Gigs.objects.all().annotate(_average_rating=Avg('orders__time'))
    serializer_class = GigsSerializerWithAvgTime
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request , *args, **kwargs):
        return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class GigsSerializerWithAvgTime(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    average_completionTime = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    def get_average_completionTime(self, obj):
        return obj.average_completionTime
    class Meta:
        model = Gigs
        fields = ['id','title','category','price','details','seller','images','average_completionTime']
```

Comment: Please don't edit in such a manner that the existing answers look out of place. The edits you had done made it look like the answers just repeated your code. You can add those in your question but please add them so that the answers don't appear out of place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate each gig with its average completion time like this:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Gigs.objects.annotate(
            _average_completionTime=Avg(
                F('gig__order_completed_time') - F('gig__order_start_time')
            )
        )
```

In your `average_completionTime` model method, you also need to use `F` expressions if `self._average_completionTime` is not set so:

```
    @property
    def average_completionTime(self):
        if getattr(self, '_average_completionTime', None):
            return self._average_completionTime
        return self.gig.aggregate(Avg(F('order_completed_time') - F('order_start_time')))
```

**UPDATE**:

I'm not able to reproduce the `'decimal.Decimal' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'` error.

No clue why, but based on [**`this`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68390799/django-aggregate-between-timezone-aware-fields) answer, you can try to use [**`ExpressionWrapper`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.ExpressionWrapper) to avoid that same error, so:

```
from django.db.models import DurationField, ExpressionWrapper, F


class GigsSerializerWithAvgTime(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Gigs.objects.annotate(
            _average_completionTime=Avg(
                ExpressionWrapper(F('gig__order_completed_time') - F('gig__order_start_time'), output_field=DurationField())
            )
        )
```

or as @Abdul Aziz Barkat has mentioned, add the `output_field` to the `Avg` aggregate like this:

```
        return Gigs.objects.annotate(
            _average_completionTime=Avg(
                F('gig__order_completed_time') - F('gig__order_start_time'), output_field=DurationField()
            )
        )
```

Comment: Sir I have tried it but getting field error **'decimal.Decimal' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'**

Comment: Can you share the full traceback with the latest code you have?

Comment: Yes sure I am editing the Question

Comment: Sir I have updated the code in question. and sorry for disturbing you again

Comment: Hey thanks! Can you also add the full traceback of the error?

Comment: Trackback of error :    https://dpaste.com/5NMLARQEA

Comment: I have also added the screenshot of error in question

Comment: Hmm weird. Does this happen if you remove the annotate in `get_queryset`?

Comment: No sir Without annotate function I was using ```queryset = Gigs.objects.all()``` and it was working

Comment: @mujahidkhan add the traceback to the _question_ (For _both_ the first and the current error) not to a _comment_ and as _text formatted as code_ not as a link.

Comment: @BrianD you don't need the `ExpressionWrapper` as aggregates can take an `output_field`, see [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#output-field)

Comment: Ah didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: @Briand this is working well when there is an entry in order table related to some gig. but If in order table if we have not the record of a gig it should return ```average_completionTime=null``` but its giving an error ```Complex aggregates require an alias```

Comment: It would probably be better to post that as a new question, adding all the latest code you have as well as the full traceback

Comment: @BrianD Sir I've added. check please! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69416145/why-getting-complex-aggregates-require-an-alias-error

Answer (score 0):

An F() object represents the value of a model field, it refers to model field values and perform database operations using them. for more details, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions

```
from django.db.models import F

let say queryset = Gigs.objects.all()

#you add '_average_completionTime' in the queryset
queryset = queryset.annotate(_average_completionTime=Avg(F('gig__order_completed_time') - F('gig__order_start_time'))
```

Comment: I have tried and getting error **TypeError: Complex aggregates require an alias**

Comment: @mujahidkhan i edited answer, you can add calculated average completion_time in queryset , so that you can access this with object of queryset.