# why getting Complex aggregates require an alias error?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset

I am working on Django where I have two models **Gigs** and **Orders** and I am calculating average Completion time of order of every gig.

in **order** model I have two fields **order start time** (which I'm sending whenever seller accepts the order) and **order completed time**  (which I'm sending when seller delivered) the order.

but the problem is that if I have data in Orders table related to some gig and I retrieve the gig then it worked perfectly but if I tries to retrieve a gig with no orders yet ( in orders table there is no record/field containing that item/gig) then it gives me following error

```
Complex aggregates require an alias
```

**Models.py**

```
class Gigs(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images = models.ImageField(blank=True, null = True, upload_to= upload_path)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    details = models.TextField()
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User,default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    @property
    def average_completionTime(self):
        if getattr(self, '_average_completionTime', None):
            return self._average_completionTime
        return self.gig.aggregate(Avg(F('orderCompletedTime') - F('orderStartTime')))

class Orders(models.Model):
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(User,default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='buyer_id')
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User,default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='seller_id')
    item = models.ForeignKey(Gigs,default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='gig')
    payment_method= models.CharField(max_length=10)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=13,default=None)
    quantity = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=13,default='new order')
    orderStartTime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    orderCompletedTime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    isCompleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**Views.py**

```
class RetrieveGigsAPI(GenericAPIView, RetrieveModelMixin):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Gigs.objects.annotate(
            _average_completionTime=Avg(
                ExpressionWrapper(F('gig__orderCompletedTime') - F('gig__orderStartTime'), output_field=DurationField()),
                filter=Q(gig__isCompleted=True),
            )
        )
    serializer_class = GigsSerializerWithAvgTime
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request , *args, **kwargs):
        return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class GigsSerializerWithAvgTime(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    average_completionTime = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    def get_average_completionTime(self, obj):
        return obj.average_completionTime
    class Meta:
        model = Gigs
        fields = ['id','title','category','price','details','seller','images','average_completionTime']
```

**Example**

for example if we have following data in orders table where item is foreign key from gigs table
[image: order table]
Now if I retrieve gig 22 it worked well and gives me all the fields in Api including average completion time but if I want to get gig 23 or any other it gives me error

but I want it should return all other fields same and average completion time : null

**full Trackback of error**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/seller/GigApi/23/

Django Version: 3.0.11
Python Version: 3.9.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'djoser',
 'accounts',
 'adminuser',
 'seller',
 'buyer',
 'corsheaders']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 374, in aggregate
    arg.default_alias
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\aggregates.py", line 65, in default_alias
    raise TypeError("Complex expressions require an alias")

During handling of the above exception (Complex expressions require an alias), another exception occurred:
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\FYP\backend\seller\views.py", line 76, in get
    return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 56, in retrieve
    return Response(serializer.data)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 548, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 246, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 515, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 1870, in to_representation
    return method(value)
  File "C:\FYP\backend\seller\serializers.py", line 21, in get_average_completionTime
    return obj.average_completionTime
  File "C:\FYP\backend\seller\models.py", line 29, in average_completionTime
    return self.gig.aggregate(Avg(F('orderCompletedTime') - F('orderStartTime')))
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 376, in aggregate
    raise TypeError("Complex aggregates require an alias")

Exception Type: TypeError at /seller/GigApi/23/
Exception Value: Complex aggregates require an alias
```

Comment: To use an "alias" do you just have to pass a keyword argument to aggregate instead of a positional argument: `return self.gig.aggregate(avg_time=F(...) - F(...))['avg_time']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Iain Shelvington has mentioned, you can set a name to the aggregate like this to resolve the error:

```py
return self.gig.aggregate(average_completion=Avg(F('orderCompletedTime') - F('orderStartTime')))['average_completion']
                          # ^^^ Add this
```

And additionally, since in the `get_queryset` it can potentially already have a calculated value, you can try to change `getattr` to `hasattr` and just return:

```py
    @property
    def average_completionTime(self):
        if hasattr(self, '_average_completionTime'):
            return self._average_completionTime

        return self.gig.aggregate(
            average_completion=Avg(F('orderCompletedTime') - F('orderStartTime'))
        )['average_completion']
```

This is to check if `_average_completionTime` is already calculated for a gig instance, to prevent calculating it again.

Comment: We need your help on other issue. can you please help us. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69445362/how-to-get-new-data-at-run-time-from-django