# how to get new data at run time from django?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am working on a Django project with ReactJs frontend. I have to built a simple chat application in that project where users can communicate with each other.
in django views I have following function to read messages

**Views.py**

```
class MessagesListAPI(GenericAPIView, ListModelMixin ):
    def get_queryset(self):
        condition1 = Q(sender=15) & Q(receiver=11)
        condition2 = Q(sender=11) & Q(receiver=15)
        return Messages.objects.filter(condition1 | condition2)
    serializer_class = MessagesSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request , *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

this gives me all the messages between user 11 and user 15.

on frontend I am getting these messages from rest Api by calling above function

**frontend**

```
const chatApi = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/chat/'
})
```

```
const getMessages = async() => {
        let data = await chatApi.get(`MessageRead/`).then(({data})=>data);
        setMessages(data); 
    }
```

I am calling this function in an onClick event of button. and displaying the messages by maping messages array.
[image]

problem is that at the time when these messages are open to the user. at that time if a new message(data) is added in database. I have to press that button again and call **getMessages** function again to display that message.

Is there a way to automatically get that new message(record) without calling this function again by pressing a button?

Comment: You are looking to either 1) Keep requesting data (on some set interval) from server via [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)). OR 2) Use [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), for which [Django channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is a popular library to use.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Can you please suggest me the best way and tutorial from where I can learn that